# How to set message body in Privatemsg

Tags: privatemsg

I'm using Drupal [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module and there's a requirement when a link is clicked, it should open up write new message form with recipient, subject and part of message body are already filled for the sender.

I'm getting the recipient and subject as `messages/new/$recipient/$subject` through URL but don't know how to set **message body**.

I can't change it in `admin/config/messaging/privatemsg` as there are several message types being passed but only one needs this preset message body text.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Why can't you do it, again? Why is `messages/new/$recipient/$subject/$body` bad? Won't it leave message body blank if you will omit last segment?